# Airport Extreme - NAT/Bridge Mode with fixed IP

Tags: router, nat, wifi-configuration, airport, airport-extreme

we moved to a new office with a new router/modem where I disabled the Wi-Fi signal and plugged in the ethernet to use the Airport Extrem to send out the Wi-Fi Signal through the office.

Also we have a 2nd Aiport Extrem as a repeater for the signal.

The problem is though, as we have a fixed IP address that the Airport Utility App tells me that the main Airport Extrem must be switched from "DHCP and NAT" to "brige mode"

I just tried doing that, but as soon as I do the main Aiport Extreme is missing from my network completely.

Any idea how to get all lights green and set up this properly?

Right now the Internet works though, however the orange light blinks on the main Airport Extreme.

Thanks,
Matt

[image]

ps. as mentioned above: If I set the suggested setting the router is gone for me.

Comment: I clicked "Ignore" and now the lights are green. However it seems that not everything is setup properly as the internet is working on and off again.

Comment: The Browser often shows "Connecting" or "Resolving Hosts" and is rather slow. Then again it works - so i figure something is not correctly configured.